# Can QGIS make georectified orthomosaics of group of jpegs?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I have a file full of photo's taken with a 3DR drone over a small coffee farm in Peru. My intention is to create an Orthomosaic of these photos and than use the mosaic to automate a vegetation analysis all with open source software.

I have tested AirPhotoSE, but I am running into an 'IO Error' after importing my photos and the program crashes constantly.

VisualSFM was similarly unsuccessful. Despite having downloaded the supplementary applications ( SiftGPU, PBA, and VLFeat SIFT), whenever I attempt to 'Compute Missing Matches' I get these error messages:

```
     ERROR: siftgpu failed the detection test!!
     SIFT: 0000, 4000x3000,     ERROR1
     ERROR: unable to locate sift binary.
```

I am wondering if anyone can suggest another program or approach I can take. QGIS seems like a good next program to test.

Can QGIS make georectified orthomosaics of a group of jpegs?

Answer (score 1):

There is a project called [OpenDroneMap](https://github.com/OpenDroneMap/OpenDroneMap) which you might want to investigate. Not tried it myself, but it looks like it might be able to stitch your images.

As for the VisualSFM error messages, looking at the [VisualSFM site](http://ccwu.me/vsfm/doc.html) it sounds like your GPU isn't recognised, or the driver is out of date, so it's falling back to the CPU driver, but there's a problem with your PATH.

Answer (score 1):

I asked some time ago about similar thing on qgis user mailing list - someone pointed me out that page:
https://www.mapsmadeeasy.com/

You must pay for their services.